# Mutating Java object by using side-effecting method in a loop in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, lazy-evaluation

In my Clojure code I'd like to to use a side-effecting method of Java object in a loop. My intention is to set multiple parameters of the Java object to values that I store in a map:

```
(def params {
             :param1 "value1"
             :param2 "value2"
             })
```

If I set `param1` to `"value1"` directly, it works fine:

```
(.setParam object (str :param1) "value1")
```

However, if I want to iterate over the `params` map forcing the evaluation by using `doseq`, the Java object remains untouched:

```
(doseq [[param value] params] (.setParam object (str param) value))
```

How to loop over the `params` map and use the side-effecting `setParam` method so that the Java `object` is mutated?

I believe this is likely a beginner error that would be easy to resolve for more experienced Clojure users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `str` on a keyword includes the colon in the result. Try `name` instead:

```
(doseq [[param value] params] (.setParam object (name param) value))
```

Comment: Indeed, this is the real cause why the `.setParam` call doesn't work. It doesn't have to do with forced mutation by `doseq` as I was suspecting. BTW, should I close or delete my question now that we've discovered the correct source of my error? What's the usual approach to such questions on StackOverflow?

Comment: I'd say leave it open.

Answer (score 1):

It should work, I think you're doing something else wrong.

```
user=> (def m (java.util.HashMap.))
#'user/m
user=> (doseq [[p v] params] (.put m p v))
nil
user=> m
{:param2 "value2", :param1 "value1"}
```

Comment: Ah, yes, probably no Java object expects colons in parameter names :).

Comment: Exactly, that was my omission.